# Spring integration and changing data routes

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm reading through Spring Integration documentation and I still can't get into one thing: does Spring resolve all dependencies and make that automagic IoC dependency injection at compile time or at runtime?

I believed that it is runtime job to wire available components together in a data route from gateway to  some data endpoint (e.g. DB). But since most of examples are made using DSL syntax in java, it seems that it's a compile time job.

So, glueing together beans in a data highway can be made only at compile time?

Comment: Do you mean that all data processors, jdbc connectors and all such nodes are beans that should be created defined at compile time? So I cannot create a second route in my Spring app even if it consists of the same beans that I've already declared (not the same instances obiously)?

Comment: No problem, should I frame the comments as an answer if you want to accept?

Comment: I have put my comments in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up my comments here :

1) Spring IOC container manages beans from its creation till destruction. What this means is the beans are ready in sort of a bucket, which is a ready to use application. Thus, it is necessary to create the contents of the bucket at compile time, rather then runtime. This does not include hot-swapping of beans.. I hope this is what you were looking for.

2) You can create as many routes as you want, those all beans will be put in the container.... And as far as I understand, you cannot just change your source code and synchronize it with already running one, you have to atleast do a graceful restart. There is a bottom line to this, Spring must see if all beans are properly autowired, no circular dependencies, and there is no expectation of source code during run time. Sure you can get your beans via RMI, but that doesn't count as you have declared it already. So yes, compile time it is

Answer (score 0):

The java DSL syntax is simply a different way of defining a flow definition (a series a bean definitions). The beans are still created and wired together during application initialization (runtime).

Comment: But can I change flow definition of existing beans without recompilation? I mean: stop app, change xml config of data flow, start app.

Comment: No; the definition is compiled Vs. configured. Use XML if you want to change it dynamically.